# Can I Allocate a specific memory address using pointers in c++?

Tags: c++, memory, pointers

Can I Allocate a specitic memory address using pointers in c++ ?

For example: Allocate This memory address 25D4C3FA and put 4 in it.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? (Are you in an environment without virtual memory?)

Comment: Yeah, and what if that address is already in use?

Comment: This is completely platform-specific, so you should specify what platform are you targeting and why you need to do that.

Comment: But seriously, you need to tell us not only what you want to achieve exactly, but also the exact system this program will run on.

Comment: there still exist env without virtual memory??

Comment: @UmNyobe Sure. Not everything is Windows or Linux.

Comment: @UmNyobe: uhm, almost any low-end microcontroller?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*Allocating* a specific address in your process's address space is a bit tricky and platform-specific. On Unix systems, [`mmap()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) is probably the closest you're going to get. The Windows equivalent is [`VirtualAlloc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There are, of course, no guarantees since the address might already be in use.

*Writing* to a specific address is trivial:

```
char *p = (char*)0x25D4C3FA;
*p = 4;
```

I assume you have good reasons to want to do that.

Comment: It's worth adding that on Windows, one would want to call `VirtualAlloc`.

Comment: Can you give me an example on VirtualAlloc to allocate this address 25D4C3FA

Comment: @faressoft: I think we'd be in a better position to help you if you explained where you're going with this.

Comment: I want to know if I can allocate the same address of 'a' in this example http://ideone.com/2ZJ57 to see why every time I call the function 'a' have the same address http://ideone.com/2ZJ57 it doesn't deallocated or what what happen if I allocate this address !

Comment: Take note that pointer is not integer type (unlike char datatype , which is naturally a 8-bit size integer , that's the reason why you can do char a = 65; ) , so you can't directly do this char *p = 0x25D4C3FA; , there's one method to write to specific address , that is by doing this , char *p = (char *)0x25D4C3FA;

Comment: @KerrekSB: OK, added an explicit cast :-|

Comment: But how on ARM Cortex-M Microcontrollers?

Comment: I get the error *Exception thrown: write access violation.
p was  0x25D4C3FA.* for the second line on my Visual Studio!

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, yes.

pseudo-code:

```
Pointer desiredAddress = 0xD0000000;

//allocate 1 KB at our desired address
Pointer p = VirtualAlloc(desiredAddress, 1024, 
      MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE,  
      PAGE_READWRITE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by *allocate* you actually mean *access*,

You can, but if the address is invalid or not accessible then deferencing the address will result in Undefined Behavior.
So it is not a good idea to do so.

Comment: No, in standard C++ you can't. You can set a pointer to 0x25f4c3fa and try to use it, but this is not "allocating".

Comment: @MatteoItalia: The OP means setting a pointer rather than allocating here if you read the complete q.

Comment: The question is quite ambiguous, but he specifically says "allocate" several times.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Since as you already said OP probably doesn't know what S/He wants the argument over terminology used it pointless.

Comment: @AIs Nobody said that the OP doesn't know what he/she wants - just that we don't. Either way, you should always assume that people mean what they say (and the OP said "allocate") unless you have good reason to suspect they meant something other than what they said.

Comment: And if you do, you should specifically mention that, so that it's clear that you're answering a different question than the one that was asked. The way your answer is now, someone reading it might very well be led to believe that you can allocate a specific memory address using pointers in standard C++. If you had started your answer with "I'm assuming that by 'allocate' you actually meant 'access'", it would have been unambiguous.

Comment: @sepp2k: *Nobody said that the OP doesn't know what he/she wants* it was said in the comment above mine and was stealth edited(as I see now), so those are not my words & The way I see it I answered the Q that was asked clumsily.I will add that assumption to the answer if it makes you happy.

Answer (score 0):

You can request a specific address through VirtualAlloc on Windows, and I expect other operating systems do the same, but there are no guarantees and no platform-independent means.