# Dynamical initialization of memory at a given memory address

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, hash, hashtable

Ok this might seem odd but please bear with me, I'm just a beginner. Over the past few days i have been trying to develop a general purpose hash function for maintaining an associative array with a hash table using all the best parts of hash functions like RS ,JS , ELF e.t.c to reduce hash collisions. but now the problem is even now to avoid a appreciable amount of collision i will have to use unsigned long values  with atleast 6 digits to avoid collision.

Lets just assume i just need to map names of students to their marks.So i maintain an integer array for the marks.

Now back to my question.

> The idea i thought of was to use these values as few lower order bits of of an actual memory address and then dynamically initialize memory large enough to store a integer for the marks obtained. This process is repeated for each new value added.

Now assuming i somehow managed to avoid all memory locations that would be reserved by the OS

> Is there any viable way to dynamically initialize memory at an address we like rather than letting the new operator to initialize it and then return a pointer to that address location in C++.  (i'm using gcc).

Comment: Read about [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: for a hash table use a ... table. well, an array. like.

Comment: Look up "placement operator new".

Comment: i know about an std map and all other STL but pls take a look at my question  ?

Comment: Not in portable C++. Your OS might have functions to allocate memory at a specific virtual address though, but I doubt it would work well out for your scenario - which I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @matt well to simply put it i want to dynamic initilize enough memory at a given 32 bit memory address that i explicitly provide. new operator cant decide for itself.

Comment: @brian beuning have you tried it.I was just reading through a reference in c++ FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is platform-dependant. On Unix systems, you might try using mmap(). The Windows equivalent is VirtualAlloc(). But there is no guarantee since the address might already be in use.

Comment: I found this now - this might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364582/can-i-allocate-a-specific-memory-address-using-pointers-in-c