# How to make malloc return the same address every time using MSVC?

Tags: c, visual-c++, malloc

For debugging purposes, I would like `malloc` to return the same addresses every time the program is executed, however in MSVC this is not the case.
For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int test = 5;
    printf("Stack: %p\n", &test);
    printf("Heap: %p\n", malloc(4));
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with cygwin's gcc, I get the same Stack address and Heap address everytime, while compiling with MSVC with aslr off...

```
cl t.c /link /DYNAMICBASE:NO /NXCOMPAT:NO
```

...I get the same Stack address every time, but the Heap address changes.

I have already tried adding the registry value `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\MoveImages` but it does not work.

Comment: That's not guaranteed behavior of `malloc` and is never specified anywhere. If you have other requirements you should consider using your own wrapper for `malloc` that could satisfy your requirements. But remember to only use that wrapper for the testing you need.

Comment: You can use `VirtualAlloc()` in windows to allocate a specific address. See the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364582/can-i-allocate-a-specific-memory-address-using-pointers-in-c

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude While deterministic return values are not a guaranteed behaviour of malloc, and may be unachievable in systems lacking virtual memory hardware, it is a property useful for debugging. Similarly, that's one of the reasons pseudo-random generators offer a seed function.

Comment: I suggest adding the "windows" tag to this question since it applies to all programs running under Windows, not just those compiled with MSVC.

Answer (score 2):

Both the stack address and the pointer returned by `malloc()` may be different every time. As a matter of fact both differ when the program is compiled and run on Mac/OS multiple times.

The compiler and/or the OS may cause this behavior to try and make it more difficult to exploit software flaws. There might be a way to prevent this in some cases, but if your goal is to replay the same series of `malloc()` addresses, other factors may change the addresses, such as time sensitive behaviors, file system side effects, not to mention non-deterministic thread behavior. You should try and avoid relying on this for your tests.

Note also that `&test` should be cast as `(void *)` as `%p` expects a `void` pointer, which is not guaranteed to have the same representation as `int *`.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that you may not be able to obtain deterministic behaviour from the MSVC runtime libraries.  Both the debug and the production versions of the C/C++ runtime libraries end up calling a function named  `_malloc_base()`, which in turn calls the Win32 API function [HeapAlloc()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapalloc).  Unfortunately, neither `HeapAlloc()` nor the function that provides its heap, [HeapCreate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapcreate), document a flag or other way to obtain deterministic behaviour.

You could roll up your own allocation scheme on top of `VirtualAlloc()`, as suggested by @Enosh_Cohen, but then you'd loose the [debug functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-versions-of-heap-allocation-functions?view=vs-2019) offered by the MSVC allocation functions.

Answer (score 0):

[Diomidis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61746351/2659307) suggests making a new `malloc` on top of `VirtualAlloc`, so I did that.  It turned out to be somewhat challenging because `VirtualAlloc` itself is not deterministic, so I'm documenting the procedure I used.

First, grab [Doug Lea's malloc](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html).  (The ftp link to the source is broken; use [this http alternative](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/pub/misc/).)

Then, replace the `win32mmap` function with this (hereby placed into the public domain, just like Doug Lea's malloc itself):

```
static void* win32mmap(size_t size) {
  /* Where to ask for the next address from VirtualAlloc. */
  static char *next_address = (char*)(0x1000000);

  /* Return value from VirtualAlloc. */
  void *ptr = 0;

  /* Number of calls to VirtualAlloc we have made. */
  int tries = 0;

  while (!ptr && tries < 100) {
    ptr = VirtualAlloc(next_address, size,
                       MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (!ptr) {
      /* Perhaps the requested address is already in use.  Try again
       * after moving the pointer. */
      next_address += 0x1000000;
      tries++;
    }
    else {
      /* Advance the request boundary. */
      next_address += size;
    }
  }

  /* Either we got a non-NULL result, or we exceeded the retry limit
   * and are going to return MFAIL. */
  return (ptr != 0)? ptr: MFAIL;
}
```

Now compile and link the resulting `malloc.c` with your program, thereby overriding the MSVCRT allocator.

With this, I now get consistent `malloc` addresses.

But **beware**:

- The exact address I used, `0x1000000`, was chosen by enumerating my address space using [`VirtualQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualquery) to look for a large, consistently available hole.  The address space layout appears to have some unavoidable non-determinism even with ASLR disabled.  You may have to adjust the value.
- I confirmed this works, in my particular circumstances, to get the same addresses during 100 sequential runs.  That's good enough for the debugging I want to do, but the values might change after enough iterations, or after rebooting, etc.
- This modification should *not* be used in production code, only for debugging.  The retry limit is a hack, and I've done nothing to track when the heap shrinks.